# How to get access to pygame button created from list

Tags: python, user-interface, pygame

I have a list of names, from which, with for loop, I create pygame_gui buttons. My question is how to get access to button id or at least its content after click event?

```
import pygame
import pygame_gui

pygame.init()

pygame.display.set_caption('Quick Start')
window_surface = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
background = pygame.Surface((800, 600))
background.fill(pygame.Color('#000000'))
manager = pygame_gui.UIManager((800, 600))

new_list = ['[0]', '[1]', '[2]', '[3]']

for i in range(len(new_list)):
    pygame_gui.elements.UIButton(relative_rect=pygame.Rect((150, 75+(100*i)), (100, 75)),
                                 text=new_list[i], manager=manager)

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
is_running = True

while is_running:
    time_delta = clock.tick(60)/1000.0
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            is_running = False

        if event.type == pygame.USEREVENT:
            if event.user_type == pygame_gui.UI_BUTTON_PRESSED:
                # here I would like to get access to button id or at least its content
                print('button clicked...dont know which though')

        manager.process_events(event)

    manager.update(time_delta)

    window_surface.blit(background, (0, 0))
    manager.draw_ui(window_surface)

    pygame.display.update()
```

I tried to create button in for loop as variable...

```
for i in range(len(island.market_goods)):
    new_button = pygame_gui.elements.UIButton(relative_rect=pygame.Rect((150, 75+(100*i)), (100, 75)),
                                              text=island.market_goods[i].name, manager=manager)
```

...and then use event.ui_elements

```
if event.type == pygame.USEREVENT:
    if event.user_type == pygame_gui.UI_BUTTON_PRESSED:
        if event.ui_element == new_button:
            print('new_button was clicked!')
```

but with this solution I get answer only from last button...

The only idea I have is to create list that appends button objects in for loop and then event function checks if clicked button is available in list, but I think that there might be easier solution that I dont see.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah... so that was quick...
Own question own answer..

If sb is looking for answer:

```
new_list = ['[0]', '[1]', '[2]', '[3]']
list_of_buttons = []

for i in range(len(new_list)):
    list_of_buttons.append(pygame_gui.elements.UIButton(relative_rect=pygame.Rect((150, 75+(100*i)), (100, 75)), text=new_list[i], manager=manager))
```

.

```
if event.type == pygame.USEREVENT:
    if event.user_type == pygame_gui.UI_BUTTON_PRESSED:
        if event.ui_element in list_of_buttons:
            print(list_of_buttons.index(event.ui_element))
```